# So much dependencies for installing the package 'nmap'

Tags: dependencies, debian, apt-get, nmap

I want to install the package `nmap` on debian by the command `apt-get`, but It seems that the package `nmap` depends on so many dependencies! For example It depends on the packages `imagemagick` and `x11-common`! Unless `nmap` needs the X window system !? Is everything OK?

```
# apt-get install nmap

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  dbus fontconfig fonts-droid fonts-liberation ghostscript gnuplot gnuplot-nox groff gsfonts hicolor-icon-theme imagemagick imagemagick-common libavahi-client3
  libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libblas3 libblas3gf libcairo2 libcroco3 libcups2 libcupsimage2 libdatrie1 libdbus-1-3 libdjvulibre-text libdjvulibre21 libexiv2-12
  libffi5 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgfortran3 libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-data libgs9 libgs9-common libice6 libijs-0.35 libilmbase6 libjasper1 libjbig0
  libjbig2dec0 liblcms1 liblcms2-2 liblensfun-data liblensfun0 liblinear-tools liblinear1 liblqr-1-0 liblua5.1-0 libmagickcore5 libmagickcore5-extra libmagickwand5
  libnetpbm10 libopenexr6 libpango1.0-0 libpaper-utils libpaper1 libpcap0.8 libpixman-1-0 librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common libsm6 libsvm-tools libsystemd-login0 libthai-data
  libthai0 libtiff4 libwmf0.2-7 libxaw7 libxcb-render0 libxcb-shm0 libxft2 libxmu6 libxrender1 libxt6 netpbm poppler-data psutils shared-mime-info ufraw-batch x11-common
```

Comment: This is 1 millionth live question on Stack Overflow!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen how can you tell?

Comment: Sorry, I meant 10 millionth.  I counted based on the number which was listed on the question page ^ ^

Comment: Predictably but dismayingly, it is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a problem on [Debian 7 wheezy (oldstable)](https://www.debian.org/releases/wheezy/) which was fixed in [Debian 8 jessie (stable)](https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/). Nmap requires the [liblinear1 package](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/liblinear1) in order to do IPv6 OS detection, and that package had a "recommends" dependency on [liblinear-tools](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/liblinear-tools), which further recommended [libsvm-tools](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libsvm-tools), which requires [gnuplot](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/gnuplot), and that is where the X11 dependencies are coming from. In Debian jessie and later releases, [liblinear1](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/liblinear1) downgraded the dependency on liblinear-tools to "suggests" so that this is not a problem.

To solve your particular issue, you can either upgrade to a more recent Debian release, or use `apt-get --no-install-recommends install nmap`. An even better solution, though, would be to use a recent version of Nmap built from source or installed from the official RPMs. You can use [alien](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RPM/AlienHowto) to install RPMs on a Debian system. The version of Nmap that Debian wheezy installs (6.00) is over 3 years old and has several known bugs. Debian jessie is on the (current) latest stable version, 6.47, but that is also a year old and about to be eclipsed. The latest version can always be downloaded from https://nmap.org/download.html

Comment: Install from source or convert RPM package?!? Seriously??
Better install _nmap-6.40_ from official "_wheezy-backports_" repository, see http://backports.debian.org/Instructions/ for details.

Comment: @Onlyjob That package still depends on `liblinear1` which will be provided from the wheezy repo, so it does not address the question. Not to mention that 6.40 is 2 years old, which means that compared to 6.49BETA it is missing 44 NSE scripts, 648 IPv4 OS fingerprints, 1071 service fingerprints, 9 IPv6 OS classes, and many major code improvements.

Comment: I'm not answering question but criticising second part of your answer where you explain how to install latest software to Debian "oldstable" without using package management. This hasn't been asked and it does not solve the problem either. First paragraph of your answer explains situation very well and answers the question. :)

Comment: Aw, man, I'm gonna try this method with other packages that have stupidly-large dependency sets.